# How to query an Excel sheet with a period in the column name

Tags: php, sql, excel, odbc

I have this Excel spreadsheet that I want to query from a php page using the ODBC Excel Driver. Take the following table for example:

```
tblExample
----------------------------------
| Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3. |
----------------------------------
| 1       | Mike     | 12345     |
| 2       | Sally    | 67890     |
| 3       | Mitchel  | 12345     |
| 1       | James    | 67890     |
----------------------------------
```

Now let's say I want to query each column with a LIKE statement. The first one I can query with no issues.

```
SELECT * FROM tblExample WHERE Column1 LIKE '%1%';
```

The second one is also easy to query, though I have to use `[]` brackets because of the space.

```
SELECT * FROM tblExample WHERE [Column 2] LIKE '%Mi%';
```

The third column is giving me trouble, however. When I try to query it with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tblExample WHERE [Column 3.] LIKE '%12345%';
```

I get this error:

```
37000: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] '' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.
```

I am pretty sure that it is expecting a table name after the (.), but I want to be able to just send in the column name and be done with it. Renaming the column to remove the period does work, but is not my first choice of solution.

Is there another way to send a column name with ODBC Excel that would allow me to keep the (.) in?

**PHP Code**

```
$con = odbc_connect("my_data_source_name","","",SQL_CURSOR_FORWARD_ONLY);
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM tblExample WHERE [Column 3.] LIKE '%12345%'";
$qryrst = odbc_exec($con, $stmt); --fails here
```

Comment: Can you try to use double quotes instead of square brackets?

Comment: Gave it a go with `SELECT * FROM tblExample WHERE "Column 3." LIKE '%12345%';`, but I still got the error mentioned above. Good idea though.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826763 - Try ...WHERE Column 3[.] LIKE...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tblExample WHERE [Column 3[.]] LIKE '%12345%'` resulted in `37000: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error in query expression '[Column 3[.]] LIKE '%12345%''`

Comment: Is it possible that PHP is doing something unexpected with the . in the name?

Comment: I don't think so, though I am not sure how I would know. I will add a sample of my php code, if it helps.

Comment: One other possible... in SSIS, when using and ODBC command on an Excel file you use the ` character (ASCII 96) to wrap table names rather than []. Try `Column 3.` - its a bit of a long shot, but MAY work.

Comment: @user3056839 I gave your suggestions a go, but unfortunately it resulted in the same error. I think at this point I am going to have to stick with renaming the column in Excel so that it doesn't have a period in it.

Comment: If that option is available to you, without a doubt, that is the best solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I encountered the same issue today.
Turns out the ODBC driver converts . to #.
Therefore, you should reference your column as [Column 3#].
Hope this helps.

Comment: Just had the same problem too. Too bad this answer isn't better documented out there. Thanks for answering!

Comment: You are a life saver!