# SQL field name containing "." - Query Excel file using ADO

Tags: sql, vba, ado

The Field names `[1-1:1.29.0 kWh]` and `[1-1:2.29.0 kWh]` cannot be queried and throws up the "...does not contain invalid.." error. The culprit is the ".". I have tried enclosing the field name in back ticks as well, does not work. Is there a way around without renaming the columns?

```
Sub smthng()

Dim myConn As Object
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
Dim myRset As Object
Set myRset = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
Dim connstr As String
Dim fileloc As String
Dim qrystr As String
Dim arr As Variant

Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.FullName
fileloc = xxxx

connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileloc 
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"""  

qrystr = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$L4:P24] WHERE [1-1:1.29.0 kWh] > 0"

Debug.Print connstr, qrystr
myConn.Open connstr '<-- active connection
With myRset
    .CursorType = 2 ' adOpenDynamic
    .CursorLocation = 3 ' adUseClient
    .Open qrystr, myConn
End With

Debug.Print myRset.Fields.Count, myRset.RecordCount

arr = myRset.getrows

'If Not myRset.BOF And Not myRset.EOF Then
'        myRset.MoveLast 
'        myRset.MoveFirst

'    Do While Not (myRset.EOF)
'      'do stuff
'
'    Loop
'End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337414/how-to-query-an-excel-sheet-with-a-period-in-the-column-name ?

Comment: @AlexK. It did. Thanks